# Writing to same file as part of a for-loop generates an empty file

Tags: bash, sed, zsh

I'm writing a command to prepend some text to a bunch of files which match a certain pattern:

```bsh
for file in $(find . -name "*.txt"); do sed "1s/^/hello/" $file; done
```

If I write to `stdout` or a different file (e.g. `"$file.bak"`), everything works according to plan, but when I try to have the command write back to the same file, the content of the files gets wiped out:

```bsh
for file in $(find . -name "*.txt");do sed "1s/^/hello/" $file > $file; done
```

I find the behavior surprising, could someone explain why this happens, conceptually? I'm on macOS and I've tried this in `bash` and `zsh` to the same effect.

(Note that I'm aware of `sed -i ""` for in-place writing, but I'd like to pipe the result to a different command before writing in-place.)

Comment: Some more detailed discussion you may find useful is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558773/bending-a-pipeline-back-into-its-origin)

Comment: @Inian I wouldn't mark my question as a duplicate, but it did, indirectly, show me a possible _solution_ to my problem: the `tee` utility, which I'm learning about now, seems to allow me to write back to the original file.

Comment: A correction to my previous comment: as per [this Q & A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543541/is-there-a-standard-alternative-to-sponge-to-pipe-a-file-into-itself) it does not seem that `tee` is a viable alternative to `sponge`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conceptual surprise probably is in this statement here

> but when I try to have the command write back to the same file

When using `cmd file > file` it's not `cmd` opening the file to write back into but the shell itself. And the first thing a shell does when seeing `> file` is to open the file in write mode at position 0 (thereby truncating it) and then redirect stdout to this file. So at the moment `cmd` starts to read from `file` it is already empty.

Or, a bit more formalized:

- Shell forks a new process to run `cmd` in
- New process (still running shell code) opens `file` for writing at position 0 (thereby truncating it)
- New process executes `cmd`, practically starting a new binary within the current process
- `cmd` runs with stdout pointing to `file`
- `cmd` opens `file` for reading but it is already empty at this moment

On the other hand, if you use `sed -i '1s/^/hello/' file` the file is solely managed by `sed` (which technically creates a temporary file in the background then).

Comment: Ah, ok, makes perfect sense now, thank you!