# How do I replace leading tabs with 4 spaces with sed?

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

In vim it seems possible to do like this :

```
:s/^\t\+/\=repeat('    ',len(submatch(0)))
```

I didn't find out how this translates into sed. I tried the following :

```
sed -ri "s/^\t\+/\=repeat('    ',len(submatch(0)))/g" test.txt
```

The command seems to have no effect.

Comment: You're using the `-r` option, which enables extended regular expressions: that means you need to use `+` not `\+` for the quantifier. This code looks for one leading tab followed by a plus character.

Answer (score 7):

This is what `expand` is for, e.g. `expand -t 4 file.txt`.

`expand` won't edit the original file, but you can redirect to a new file and `mv` it over the original, or use `sponge` if you have it installed, e.g.

```
    expand -t 4 file.txt > file.new && mv file.new file.txt
or 
    expand -t 4 file.txt | sponge file.txt
```

FYI, see `unexpand` to do the reverse, convert multiple spaces to tabs.

Both `expand` and `unexpand` support using fixed-width tabs (e.g. `-t 4` or `-t 8`, etc) **or** a list of tab positions (e.g. `-t 4,12,32`).  They also have options to only convert initial, leading spaces/tabs.  See the man pages for details.

---

For more info about `sponge`, see `man sponge` and [Is there a standard alternative to sponge to pipe a file into itself?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/543541/7696).  In short, it does the redirect and mv for you, using a temporary file.  BTW, never try to redirect stdout to the same file that's currently being used as stdin.  The shell will overwrite it before it even gets read.

`sponge` is from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

---

PS: See also [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) or one of many other similar source-code reformatting tools.

Comment: expand has at least the -i for the leading tabs, which is what I want, but it has not the -i from sed to replace in the file directly, it would be good if I could do something like `expand -i -t 4 */**`. So if I want to replace in , say, all java files, I would do something like : `find . -type f -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 -Ifile sh -c 'expand -i -t 4 file > file.new && mv file.new file'` ?

Comment: I'd use `find ... -exec` and not bother with xargs.   Something like `find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do t=$(mktemp); expand -i -t 4 "$f" > "$t" && mv "$t" "$f"  || rm "$t"; done' sh {} +`.   Or, with sponge: find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do expand -i -t 4 "$f" | sponge "$f" ; done' sh {} +`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat -T /tmp/test.txt
^I^I^I3^I<= this final tab should remain
^I^I2
^I1
```

Using sed:

```
sed ':loop;s/^\( *\)\t/\1    /;tloop' /tmp/test.txt | cat -T
            3^I<= this final tab should remain
        2
    1
```

The above sets up a loop (labeled, ironically enough, `loop`) that captures any leading spaces and a leading tab; replaces the spaces and converts the tab to 4 spaces; if successful (`t`) it branches back to the loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35017207/493161

Comment: This will break if there's already mixed leading whitespace, space-tab-tab or something. `sed ':1;s/^\(\t*\)\t/\1    /;t1'`

Comment: It will, for sure. But it works for the question presented.